# Submit button inside modal

Tags: javascript

I have `submit` button inside a modal. However, this doesn't trigger. How can I get it work.

```
$('#test').on('shown.bs.modal', function (event) {
    $('.submit-button').on('submit', function(event) {
        console.log('submit');
    });
});



<div class="modal" role="dialog" id="test">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">TestModal</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                   <h1>Modal Data</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default submit-button">Click For Modal</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: [„Note that the submit event fires on the <form> element itself, and not on any <button> or <input type="submit"> inside it.”](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event)

Answer (score 1):

Submit buttons only work when you wrap it inside a  tag, also change the type to submit.

```
<form>
 <button type="submit" >Submit</button>
</form>
```